# pop_back() causes "Vector subscript out of range"

Tags: c++

I'm making a program just to practice vectors and this has me stumped. The point of the program was to make a tournament to help people choose between restaurants.

Here is the code that causes an error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

const int ITEMS_PER_MATCHUP = 2;

using namespace std;

int PromptChoice(string first, string second, string helpMessage = "") {
    string input;
    while (true) {
        cout << "Which restaurant do you prefer, " << first << "(1) or " << second << "(2)? ";
        cin >> input; //no need to protect as it is going into a string variable
        if (input == "first" || input == "1" || input == "left" || input == "First" || input == "Left") {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (input == "second" || input == "2" || input == "right" || input == "Second" || input == "Right") {
            return 1;
        }
        // if the response was not recognized
        else cout << endl << helpMessage << endl << "Please enter 1 or 2" << endl << "Please try again." << endl << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<string> list = { "Burger Place", "Italian Place", "Soup And Salad Place", "BBQ Place" };

    vector<int> stillInTheRunning;
    for (int index = 0; index < list.size(); index++) { //populates an array full of values 0 to the size of the array
        stillInTheRunning.push_back(index);
    }

    int matchupsThisRound = stillInTheRunning.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < matchupsThisRound; i += ITEMS_PER_MATCHUP) { //ITEMS_PER_MATCHEP == 2

        int choice = PromptChoice(list[stillInTheRunning[i]], list[stillInTheRunning[i + 1]]);
        //stillInTheRunning.erase(stillInTheRunning.begin() + i + choice);
        stillInTheRunning.pop_back();

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < stillInTheRunning.size(); i++) { //print the vector
        cout << endl << stillInTheRunning[i] << endl;
    }

    system("pause"); //I know I know don't use system. just for debuging?
}
```

If I understand the error it usually happens when you try to visit a vector index that is out of range. Something bigger than `vector.size() - 1` but in this case it happened when I was trying to use `vector.erase()`

Thinking perhaps I just mugged the for loop I tried switching to pop_back() because I thought you can't mess that one up. But I still got the error.

Playing around with it I tried commenting out a few things.

Like if I comment out the prompting function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matchupsThisRound; i += ITEMS_PER_MATCHUP) { //ITEMS_PER_MATCHEP == 2
        //int choice = PromptChoice(list[stillInTheRunning[i]], list[stillInTheRunning[i + 1]]);
        //stillInTheRunning.erase(stillInTheRunning.begin() + i + choice);
        stillInTheRunning.pop_back();
    }
```

No error

And if I comment out the pop_back():

```
for (int i = 0; i < matchupsThisRound; i += ITEMS_PER_MATCHUP) { //ITEMS_PER_MATCHEP == 2
        int choice = PromptChoice(list[stillInTheRunning[i]], list[stillInTheRunning[i + 1]]);
        //stillInTheRunning.erase(stillInTheRunning.begin() + i + choice);
        //stillInTheRunning.pop_back();
    }
```

also no error.

What is causing the problem???

Comment: `vector<>::pop_back()` removes the last element from vector, `vector<>::erase()` one or multiple with explicit location. However, both methods require that the "addressed" elements are existing before. Look in the debugger, what the size element does contain before or just `cout` `size()` of vector before removal.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at that. The size at the time of error was 4

Comment: Did you consider this: Everytime, you use `vector<>::erase()` with certain `begin() + i`, all the following elements are shifted one step to front. Thus `i` is increasing but `size()`is decreasing. In the "middle" of your iteration, `i` gets bigger than `size()`. Removing from vector this way is better done from back to front.

Comment: @KyleStorey The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

I found it!

its here

```
PromptChoice(list[stillInTheRunning[i]], list[stillInTheRunning[i + 1]])
```

on the second run of the for loop i = 2;
after poping off one item off the back the vector's size was now 3 instead of 4 so stillInTheRunning[i + 1] was trying to get the item in index 3 which now does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you `pop_back`, the size of `stillInTheRunning` decreases, but `matchupsThisRound` stays the same, so eventually the loop reaches the point where `i+1` is out of the `stillInTheRunning`'s range.

Also it's a bit weird that you're increasing `i` by 2 every cycle, but `pop_back` only once.